# How can I make a static bitmap that overrides everything?

Tags: wxpython

I need a wx.StaticBitmap() that get on top of any widget contained in a certain frame. I already tried with wx.STAY_ON_TOP style, but I believe it only works for those widgets situated in the same, direct container.

Let's say I have a frame, the frame has as background a static image, on which a panel is situated, itself containing several other widgets. Now how could I make a static image, or anything else that could display an image, that has as parent the main frame or the background image, but if situated on the top of the panel it always overrides it.

Making the panel itself the parent of the overriding image is not an option

I also have to mention the fact that the panel is generated after an enter window event.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wx.Dialog and use its ShowModal() method to show your bitmap on top of everything else. You could also just hide the panel with the other widgets and show the one with the bitmap. There's this fun [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) on how to do just that.